# Eigenvector definition and negative eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, definition

A usual definition for eigenvectors are the "Almost all vectors change direction when multiplied by a matrix $A$. Certain exceptional vectors $x$ are in the same direction as $Ax$. These are called eigenvectors." (definition in Strang book).

My question is when the eigenvalue is negative, it means the vector is in the opposite direction right ?. It means the vector did change the direction and the new direction is 180 degrees of the original vector.  Am I wrong ?

Comment: That’s not really a definition of an eigenvector but an explanation that’s intended to give you an intuition and motivation for the concept. Here “same direction” basically means “is parallel to” or “lies on the same line through the origin.“

Comment: The more precise definition for eigenvectors/eigenvalues are that given a matrix $A$, an eigenvector for $A$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a vector such that $Av=\lambda v$.  That is to say, $A$ acts on the vector the same way that scalar multiplication acts on the vector.  Note that in the case of positive eigenvalues this does mean that $v$ and $Av$ lie in the same "direction" but it avoids the confusion caused by negative eigenvalues or zero eigenvalues.

Comment: In a strict mathematical sense, it is the same direction, as $x$ and $-x$ define the same subspace / line. Direction in many mathematical context doesn't have an orientation. The usage doesn't agree with the everyday usage.

Answer (score 2):

Think of $Ax=\lambda x$ as meaning the effect of the transformation $A$ on the vector $x$ is equivalent to a scalar multiplication of the vector. Vectors for which this is true under the transformation are known as eigenvectors and the corresponding scalar called eigenvalues.

You have described a situation where $\lambda < 0$ and so the vector points in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. If $AX=\lambda X$ where$ \lambda <0$, then $AX$ is in the oposite direction of X but still on the same line.

Things get worse if you have a complex eigenvalue and a complex eigenvector where you can not even say, they stay on the same line.